# How to run a .bat file in web application after hosting in iis?

Tags: asp.net, batch-file, iis-6

hi i have a problem in running a .bat file in server. In local i used

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"D:\Test\Sop_Test\Test.bat";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
}
```

the .bat file will create a new calculator in the D: drive of the server

So after i click on submit button submit_Click will run the bat file and create calcualtor in D: drive of server

I hosted the application in the IIS server its not running.

Comment: Where do you expect that calculator to show up? This command will run on the *server*.

Comment: @HansKesting: the bat file is written in such a way that an calculator application will be in created in D: drive

Comment: When the server starts that app, it will run *on the server* (and probably without a screen to show it on). Note that on your DEV machine, "client" and "server" are the same machine so there it might appear to work, only to fail in the real installation. You **can not** start a process on the client's machine (what if the command was 'format C:'?).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the .bat file to the wwwroot folder of your project. I suspect IIS can't find it since the D drive is outside the jurisdiction of IIS.